# Why doesn't my private key's public key generate the correct public address?

Tags: addresses, private-key, public-key, keccak, ecdsa

Private Key: `9ccbcabf23e271183dbed503b43277f4c6eee9ac918cd6cda75ebb73ceb35c7d`

Corresponding Public Address: `0xa73Fb234B1773ed7b115D18A1f0a15579bA2C1e1` (check for yourself on MyCrypto, for example)

One can generate the Public Key from the Private Key: `25b867253fe38ac7ed594f54b4f55fa18c49ced332fc352991e48a77ab7816c759d46cab51a59d9833cd6d958cc752ad95f10bbe469b364db2de5d3535417966`

This Public Key, however, does not seem to be produce the Public Address above. Instead, after running it through keccak256, then taking the last 20 bytes, we're left with: `0xaa72e09d258da5496a7e6628e09207ec382e478a`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to hash the bytes of the public key (not the public key string).

In Javascript https://runkit.com/embed/2w4f7dvkz2lg

```
keccak256 = require('js-sha3').keccak256;

keccak256(new Buffer('25b867253fe38ac7ed594f54b4f55fa18c49ced332fc352991e48a77ab7816c759d46cab51a59d9833cd6d958cc752ad95f10bbe469b364db2de5d3535417966', 'hex')).slice(24)
```

> "a73fb234b1773ed7b115d18a1f0a15579ba2c1e1"

Note how the public key is put in a Buffer.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not working with Javascript, so this is the problem. Looks like my keccak algorithm will only accept strings. Oy.

Comment: If it's not obvious, I'm using PHP. Groan, I know. I can turn the produced Public Key in to its bytes, and confirm they match what JS libraries are seeing. So, now to pass those bytes to the hashing algorithm in a way that is acceptable, since it will only handle strings. I've attempted to simply "implode" the byte array in to a long string, but that didn't work. Any clever ideas?

Comment: Holy sweet god I got it. Just hex2bin($publicKey) before passing it in to the hash. Praise the lord. Thank you.

Comment: @EvilJordan Feel free to [post your own](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) (PHP) answer also.  (It was not obvious at all that you were using PHP.)

Comment: @EvilJordan Thank you! I could kiss your feet right now lol. I have been trying to figure out exactly the same thing for 2 days

Comment: Many years later, I was alerted to some activity on this question. My response to all of it with my full solution was deleted by overzealous mods. Here's a link to it: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/39945/why-doesnt-my-verification-of-a-signed-message-signature-work-in-php

If that link stops working, well then there's probably no way you're reading this because it's within the same stackexchange.

Comment: @EvilJordan Good link and I upvoted your answer.